How to setup a beta versioning in Swagger endpoint?
In my WebApi project (c# and .net8) I successfully setup the following definition:

For version 1.0 I have these endpoints:

However for beta I wanna have something like: /beta/api/Auth/Logon.
Almost similar to what Microsoft have with their Graph Explorer endpoint:

Currenty I'm using version 2.0 to distinguish api versions.
Any idea how to do this? This what I have in the code:
namespace My.API.Controllers
{
   [ApiVersion("2.0")]
   [Route("v{version:apiVersion}/api/[controller]")]
   [ApiController]
   public class AdminController : ControllerBaseExtra
   {
       private readonly ILoggerManager _logger;
       private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
       private readonly ISessionUtility _sessionUtility;
       private HttpClient _client;

       public AdminController(ISessionUtility sessionUtility, IConfiguration configuration, ILoggerManager logger)
       {
           _configuration = configuration;
           _logger = logger;
           _sessionUtility = sessionUtility;
           _client = new HttpClient(new LoggingHandler(logger, new HttpClientHandler()));
       }

       /// <summary>
       /// Gets list of available environments.
       /// </summary>
       /// <returns></returns>
       [AllowAnonymous]
       [HttpGet]
       [Route("/v{version:apiVersion}/api/[controller]/Environments")]
       [ApiExplorerSettings(GroupName = "beta")]
       [ProducesResponseType(type: typeof(List<GWEnvironments>), statusCode: 200)]
       [ProducesResponseType(type: typeof(string), statusCode: 400)]
       [Produces("application/json", "application/xml")]
       public ActionResult<List<GWEnvironments>> Environments()
       {
       }
  }

}
Thank's in advance.

You can deploy a beta version of your app and use a reverse proxy to route /v* to your productive API and route /beta to your beta API. P.S, please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

@MindSwipe, thank's for your reply. do you have any link or sample code on how to do this? Sorry am kinda new on this subject.

Tried [ApiVersion(2.0,"beta")]? That should hopefully work also for the swagger generator you use but your version is then rather v2.0-beta then beta. When you use a revers proxy your swagger endpoint will not know about and can't show it as your swagger generator looks only at your code to generate the openapi description. If you need exactly beta but my suggestion work you then can think about deriving your own APiVersion Attribute that uses a different FormatProvider that then might allow "beta".

ApiVersion has a prescribed format which cannot be changed. This is important for collation, sorting, and comparison. For example, 1.0, 1.0-beta. You could define like:[ApiVersion(1.0,"beta")].
Actually no need define the ApiVersion for your beta api which can also achieve your requirement, just add the [Route] and [ApiExplorerSettings] attribute like below:
[Route("beta/api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
[ApiExplorerSettings(GroupName = "beta")]
public class BetaAdminController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("Logon")]
    public IActionResult BetaLogon()
    {
        // Beta API method
        return Ok("Beta Logon successful");
    }
}

Be sure the Program.cs configure like below:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using Asp.Versioning;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    // Generate Swagger documentation for both versions
    options.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "My API v1", Version = "v1" });
    options.SwaggerDoc("beta", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "My Beta API", Version = "beta" });
});
builder.Services.AddApiVersioning(options =>
{
    options.ReportApiVersions = true;
    options.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
    options.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1, 0);
    options.ApiVersionReader = new UrlSegmentApiVersionReader();
}).AddApiExplorer(options =>
{
    options.GroupNameFormat = "'v'VVV";
    options.SubstituteApiVersionInUrl = true;
});

builder.Services.AddProblemDetails();
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    //app.UseSwaggerUI();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "v1");
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/beta/swagger.json", "Beta");
    });
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseExceptionHandler();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();

Also be sure add the package:
<PackageReference Include="Asp.Versioning.Http" Version="8.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Asp.Versioning.Mvc.ApiExplorer" Version="8.1.0" />


Removing the version from the route and class attribute fix the issue. I never thought of that.  Thank's alot.
